# Android to WCF using JSON 400 bad request and null pointer

Tags: android, wcf, nullpointerexception, bad-request

I'm trying to save some information from a user that is saved on the android phone to a WCF service. I'm getting a 400 error from the phone and when I try to send the same request to the server using fiddler (when testing on my localhost) my visual studio's pops up a null pointer in my save method. I'm following this example to the tee and its just not working: [Tutorial](http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2010/05/10/Comsuming-WCF-Services-With-Android.aspx)

Here some of my code:
Here's my user object in the WCF service:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember(Name= "userid")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "username")]
    public string username { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "password")]
    public string password { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "information")]
    public Byte[] information { get; set; }
}
```

Operation contract in my IService

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
        RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "saveUser")]
    Boolean saveUser(User user);
```

^ this method is throwing a null pointer because the user is null. I have tried changing the WebMessageBodyStyle to WrappedRequest but that doesn't help.

Heres the android code for sending the POST Request:

```
JSONStringer user = new JSONStringer()
                .object()
                    .key("user").object()
                    .key("userid").value("1").key("username").value(appState.getCurrentUser().username)
                        .key("password").value(appState.getCurrentUser().password)
                        .key("information").value(str.toString())
                    .endObject()
                .endObject();
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(user.toString());
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(new URI(url));
            request.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            request.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

^ the response is giving me a 400 error from the server.

Here is the fiddler sending the json to the localhost:
[Here's the picture](http://www.mediafire.com/i/?2xxkzwle2xzl61w)
I added the content-length but in the picture it says 0. it really is 86.
Any help would be a appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest you use `JSONObject` and `JSONObject.toString()` instead - it's clearer and more useful.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the request using Fiddler?

Comment: I added the picture at the bottom using fiddler

Comment: a.ch. - I switched it to a JSONObject and it didn't change a thing. Still 400 error. I know the 400 is because of the null pointer of the user object being sent in is null. Why would the JSON not be parsed right when it gets to the method? I have all the data members in the JSON object and the object name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at how I was sending the byte[] it was really a string and when the JSON Object got to the service the service couldn't figure out where to put this information string. I feel like a complete noob after finding this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform a POST request from [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and your request should be something as below:

```
POST http://localhost/SampleApp/Service1.svc/saveUser HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost

{"userid":1,"username":"testuser","password":"testpassword","information":null}
```

Comment: I added the picture to the main post. I followed what you asked, then added the content-length for it. It still sent back a 400.

Comment: I added the port to it because I forgot to and visual studio's still put a null pointer on the user being sent to the service. So its now getting the request.

Comment: Can you post how your raw request looks like??

Comment: I have looked at the raw request and i think the reason for 400 bad request is the value being passed for the information property. You are  trying to send a string for "information" which is of type byte array. Just replace with null and see if it works

Comment: I tried it and heres a screenshot with vs and fiddler right next to each other. http://www.mediafire.com/?p9z6fx1l8s2e5ti. Thank you Rajesh.

Comment: From the screenshot i guess you are not getting a error but the user object is null on the server side

Comment: Thats kind of been the problem. The WCF service should be receiving the JSON and converting it into a User object but isn't. Any ideas?

Comment: That is strange. Can you try to remove the BodyStyle attribute and see if that works. Also is there a sample of the project for me to have a look at. If yes can you email it to rajeshsv.5@gmail.com

Comment: I tried to remove the body and it didn't do anything. I sent you the project. I sent you the WCF project that I have.

Comment: The email is not getting through. Heres mine: slai47@live.com

Answer (score 0):

Some times **Bad request** is a false error. 
For example, if you have a ***WritePermissionException*** in WCF server side, you might get this **Bad request**. It might confuse you and make you suspicious of your JSON string or something relevant to your request, but indeed the item caused error is something irrelevant. It took me a lot of time to debug this bloody **Bad request**. 
So in my opinion:

> Best way to resolve this error is:

- enabling **diagnostics** config in web.config file of wcf service.

`<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Traces.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>`

- then, If you have a publish from wcf, host it on a local IIS, and call it locally

**Note:** to call a REST wcf method you can use **REST clients** like (**Advanced REST Client** for example) which are available as extensions in chrome/firefox.